# Drupal Webform : set SCORE on each SELECT Options?

Tags: drupal, html-select, drupal-webform

I have **webforms on drupal with multiple select options** (radio).
And in my select, I want to say option 1 : gives 2 points, option 2 : give 1 point, etc... For after **display on a webpage : your score is 12/20 points**.

example :
A bear can be ... ?

- 0|White  <- response give 2 points
- 1|Yellow <- response give 0 point
- 2|Brown  <- response give 2 points
- 3|Dark   <- response give 1 points

**The question is : how to store the point of select options because there is only key|value in the admin interface? 
In fact : how to add infos each select option row?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, that I do :

I fill the option list with :

key_score|description

And i use explode function with _ seprator.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be to associate key with points. Thus 0 corresponds to 2 points, 1 to 0 point, 2 to 2 points and 3 to 1 point.
Thus on submission you would look at user responses and then calculate based on the responses to those particular question.

Thus under `form settings` would set the redirection location to a page where you process this logic and then redirect from there or show the output on the same page.